# CI Validate request with special characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using code igniter framework.

How to validate the request that accepts alpha, numeric and special characters.(space, comma,dashes, and forward-slash)

example:

**Controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required|xss_clean|custom_alpha_numeric');
```

**MY_Form_validation.php**

```
public function custom_alpha_numeric($str)
{
    $valid = (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9 .,-\-]+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    return $valid;
}
```

is there a way to accept forward slash in my validation?

Comment: CI Have own security class plus also security helpers please go through them

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad I didn't find any security helpers that solve my problem. about validation that accept alpha, numeric, and selected sepecial characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to search for a meta-character that has special meaning in a regular expression, you need to [escape that character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).  You escape a character using `\`, so:

```
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9 .,-\-\/]+$/i", $str)
```

In fact you are already doing exactly that for the `-`, because inside `[]` that character has special meaning (signifying a range), whereas you want to explicitly match that specific character.  You should probably remove the other `-` in there I think?

```
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9 .,\-\/]+$/i", $str)
```

Alternatively, another option is to use something other than `/` as the delimiter.  [From the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

If you use a different delimiter, the slash becomes just another character.  So for eg using `#`:

```
preg_match("#^[a-z0-9 .,\-/]+$#i", $str)
```

Comment: Cool. You save my day. Thank you